# Tensorflow: Jpeg input for model

Tags: python, tensorflow, jpeg

I'm currently working with the transfer learning retrain.py file and have a basic VGG16 model I made with pretrained weights. I was looking at the inception v3 graph in tensorboard to see how it accepts jpeg images of varying values.
[Inception V3 input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFSPI.png) I went through what each operation is and I think I have it set up correctly, but apparently not.

```
self.input_image = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
self.decode_jpeg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(self.input_image, channels=3, ratio = 1, fancy_upscaling=True, try_recover_truncated=False)
self.cast = tf.cast(self.decode_jpeg, tf.float32)
self.multi = tf.expand_dims(self.cast, 0)
self.sized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(self.multi, [224, 224], align_corners=False)
```

This is what I use to test it.

```
prob = sess.run(vgg16.output, feed_dict={vgg16.input_image: 'laska.jpg'})
```

So I'm just passing it a string of the name of the jpg in the folder. It's telling me that...

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '()'
```

So what am I doing wrong? What can I do to get so I can transplant my model into the retrain.py file?

Comment: First I would try specifying absolute path.

Comment: You are using input_image as a string. You should instead read the contents of the path and pass that.